# Wagtail translate the page slug (fully translate url)

Tags: django, language-translation, wagtail

My Wagtail settings are working correctly, I'm able to go to the same page (translated) using the /en/ and /fr/, but i wanted to fully translate the url so that i could do

/en/home

/fr/vin

I'm currently using [this plugin](https://github.com/infoportugal/wagtail-modeltranslation) to make my wagtail Page translatable, but i can't manage to make the slug part work

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting any particular errors?

I'm using wagtail-modeltranslation as well and have translated slugs working fine.

Comment: Did you changed some of the code in the wagtail Page route() ? Which versions are you using ?  Thanks for your response :D

Comment: Wagtail 1.6, I only had to fix some of the route() code for a RoutablePageMixin page. I also had to make a couple of other changes to the way it pulls up links to work better with wagtailmenus, but everything else worked as is. What problems are you having? Slug fields should be translated by default, and fully routable if setup in urls.py correctly.

Comment: @Programming123 Hello, I have a similar issue, the slug field is indeed translated, I mean it takes its value from the title (in the same language), but going to the page like this ar/slug-page-in-english gives 404 error, because the slug is in Arabic for this language and I had to change the slug manually and make it exact the same as the English slug